# How can we understand Isaiah 6:1?

Tags: isaiah

Isaiah 6:1 (KJV)

> 1 In the year that king Uzziah ***died*** I saw also the Lord sitting upon a throne, high and lifted up, and his train filled the temple.

Could this have referred to his natural death or him being stricken with leprosy (2 Chronicles 26:19-20) when he attempted to offer incense on the temple?

Comment: "**Uzziah died**".  Why is that ambiguous?

Comment: II Chron 26:21 includes three phrases "until the day he died" and "lived in a separate house" and "banned from the temple", that strongly indicate that Uzziah lived for some time with his leprosy, enough to warrant a separate house and a ban. AFAIK there is no OT instance of leprosy being a cause of death. It is usually related to as a result of some transgression. Maybe you need to clarify the question?

Answer (score 1):

In Isaiah 1.1, it is mentioned that the lived **during the reigns of Uzziah, Jotham, Ahaz and Hezekiah, kings of Judah**. Since he lived longer than Uzziah, and his son Jotham, the most plausible interpretation would be the year of the death of king Uzziah.

Also, according to EDWARD REESE, FRANK R. KLASSEN ([The Reese Chronological Bible](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0871231158)), it has appened in the year of his death (this reference is not actually about this specific text, but the authors tried their best to put the Bible in chronological order in this book, and you can see there that they put this text in the same year as Uzziah's death).